# Shell Script works fine manually, but fails to exectue through Crontab

Tags: shell, cron, raspbian

So i can't seem to fix this issue i'm having with Crontab. I have a shell script i want to run every 15 minutes. I can execute the script manually but Crontab will not launch it successfully. It's weird, I'll set it to execute at a certain time and i can check that the process is running, but it never actually executes. Here's the settings i have in Crontab.

```
0, 15, 30, 45 * * * root  /home/rpitc/Desktop/Script/Refresh
```

Here's what the Shell Script looks Like.

```
#!/bin/bash

service=wfica

if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
echo "$service is running!!!"
else
/home/rpitc/Desktop/Script/Iceweasel.sh & /home/rpitc/Desktop/Script/Login.sh
fi
```

I've read on here that it could be the path that's creating the issue so what i did was copy all of scripts to the /bin path changed the scripts appropriately, but it still would not execute. Please help, this is being ridiculous!

Comment: It may be an issue of permissions.

Comment: Not really a solution to your problem but shouldn't these be the other way round `grep -v grep | grep $service`

Comment: Why do you have spaces after your commas?

Comment: Sorry Jonathan, that was a typo on my end when i was writing the post. My Crontab settings do not reflect the spaces. To Jidder...not sure i follow what your saying...I've done the following.    chmod 777 to the path. shouldn't that grant the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Jidder's comment was that `grep -v grep` is usually used to ignore `grep X` used to find a process. But that only (really) works if you run `grep X` *before* you run `grep -v grep` since you are trying to filter the first grep's output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the syntax should be (whitout "root" and without spaces), when using "crontab -e":

```
0,15,30,45 * * * /home/rpitc/Desktop/Script/Refresh
```

If you're using a file in "/etc/cron.d/", the crontab entry should look like:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * root /home/rpitc/Desktop/Script/Refresh
```

Comment: I'm editing Crontab within /etc/crontab. if i try to edit /etc/cron.d it shows New Bufer. Should i add the command to cron.d instead?

Comment: ok i see ... /etc/crontab should be fine with the 2nd syntax. In my opinion its better to use the command "crontab -e", because there is a syntax check included. !! be sure there are no spaces in the comma seperated list of minutes!!!

Comment: This is weird. So i have removed the 15 minute variables that way i can test this more frequently. I'll set it to hit at specific time. I check processes once it hits the X time set in Crontab i can see it running as a process, but then all of a sudden it stops running. it does not want to execute. What is going on?